# chmod unable to change group permission on cygwin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cygwin, chmod, chown

I am trying to copy files to an AWS instance using SCP but am running into permission denied error as below,i tried to change the group name to "Users" as well which didnt work either?can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this?

```
 drwx------+ 1 username      NA+Group(513)    0 May 10 23:33 .ssh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrators NA+Group(513) 1692 May  5 17:00 ngc.pem
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrators NA+Group(513) 1692 May  8 12:47 test.pem
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrators NA+Group(513) 1464 May  8 13:45 test.ppk

username@machine ~
$ scp -i test.pem index.html ec2-publicip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection

username@machine ~
$ chown usernam1 test.pem
chown: changing ownership of 'test.pem': Permission denied

username@machine ~
$ chown :Users test.pem
chown: changing group of 'test.pem': Permission denied
```

Comment: what is the output with `-v` option? `scp -v -i test.pem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission denied does not relate to the permissions of the .pem file in your computer, but to the permissions of the .pem file to the server it is trying to access. First - you need to specify the specific user you are trying to scp into. For example, if this is an Ubuntu server, the correct syntax for the command would be - `scp -i test.pem index.html ubuntu@ec2-publicip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:.`, that will copy the file to the home folder of the ubuntu user.

Comment: ,where would the above command copy to?I want to copy to /var/www

Comment: The above command will copy to the ubuntu user's home dir, if you want to copy straight to /var/www you can replace this path with the dor at the end of the command ive written, but this will only work if ubuntu has write permissions on this folder.